# impossible to publish artifacts for.... java.io.IOException: missing artifact lib#MyService;1.0!MyService.jar

Tags: build, artifactory, ivy

Basically I am exploring IVY, to version my binary artifacts and how to do version control automatically using ivy. I found that publish, pubrevision could help me out.

Hence I am trying to publish my jar through IVY. However I am getting below error and build failed.

impossible to publish artifacts for lib#MyService;working@Localhost java.io.IOException: missing artifact lib#MyService;1.0!MyService.jar

Please find my ivy.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:m="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/maven">
    <info organisation="lib" module="MyService" />
    <configurations defaultconfmapping="default->default;sources->sources;test->default">
        <conf name="sources" transitive="false" visibility="private" />
        <conf name="test" transitive="false" visibility="private" />
        <conf name="default" transitive="false" />
    </configurations>

    <publications>
        <artifact name="MyService" type="jar"/>
    </publications>

    <dependencies defaultconf="default">
        <dependency org="lib" name="commons-logging-1.1" rev="1.1" />
        <dependency org="lib" name="commons-collections-3.2" rev="3.2" />
        <dependency org="lib" name="commons-beanutils"  rev="1.7.0" conf="default" />
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Publish task : Note: dist will resolve my dependency and compile and jar 
build.xml

```
<target name="publish" depends="dist">
  <ivy:publish resolver="local" pubrevision="1.0" module="MyService" status="release" forcedeliver="true" update="true">
    <artifacts pattern="publish/[organisation]-[artifact].[ext]"/>
  </ivy:publish>  
</target>
```

MyService.jar is being created in my build folder.

Can you please assist me, what is wrong with my code. I am pretty new to IVY. So any inputs will be appreciated very much.

Thanks.

Comment: What is you folder structure? That is where are build.xml, ivy.xml, and jars.

Comment: Does the file "publish/lib-MyService.jar" exist when you run the publish task? Unusual naming convention but that is what your configured pattern is looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your comments... The problem is with my jar name. IVY is looking for the jar MyService-1.0.jar but I was having MyService.jar.. Hence I got struck with IO Exception.

Comment: Can anyone suggest, how do I increment version of my jar automatically. For eg, Everytime the jar version should be incremented when I build it. MyService-1.0.jar, MyService-1.1.jar ......